# how to add Notes in on a webview iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have an iPhone application with a UIWebView as it's core UI and this web view shows some data that I want to add notes next to, an example scenario would be:

1. The User will select a text in the webview and a pop up menu
   appears.
2. They will press AddNotes button.
3. An UI textview window should appear to write in.
4. The user should press save and the notes should be saved regarding
   the location he press the AddNotes button in.

Can anyone help partially or completely?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to know about the selected test using the [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library:

```
- (BOOL) isSelectionActive
{
    NSString * resultStr = [self.contentView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                            @"rangy.getSelection().isCollapsed"];

    NSLog(@"resultStr: %@", resultStr );

    if ([resultStr isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

When you get to know that the selection has been made then animate a UITextfield, so that user will be able to enter text in it.